# How does click-cell.bs.table works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I want to expand the below row of a table by clicking a table cell of a above row. Now I'm doing it with `click-row.bs.table`. I'm using bootstrap table. How can I do it using `click-cell.bs.table`?

```js
emailRecTable.on("click-row.bs.table", function(e, row, $tr) {
    if ($tr.next().is('tr.detail-view')) {
        emailRecTable.bootstrapTable('collapseRow', $tr.data('index'));
    } else {
        emailRecTable.bootstrapTable('expandRow', $tr.data('index'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Please can you provide your code ?

Comment: How can you expand a row by clicking the cell within the row? By inference the row has to be collapsed to begin with, so surely you cannot even see the cell to click it...? A working example would help a lot here.

Comment: i edited the question. please check.

Answer (score 0):

use `data-click-to-select="true"`